# What character should be escaped in Regex

Tags: ios, regex, swift, escaping

I have been trying to use the following regex.

```
^(?=.{8,16}$)(([a-zA-Z0-9])\\2?(?!\\2))(?=(.*[a-zA-Z]){1,})(?=(.*[\\d]){1,})|(?=(.*[\\W])(?=(.*[[]{}()<>.,;:\'\")){1,}])(?!.*\\s).{8,16}$
```

but I get `NSInternalInconsistencyException` error.

> reason: 'Can't do regex matching, reason: Can't open pattern U_REGEX_MISSING_CLOSE_BRACKET (string aa, pattern ^(?=.{8,16}$)(([a-zA-Z0-9])\2?(?!\2))(?=(.*[a-zA-Z]){1,})(?=(.*[\d]){1,})|(?=(.*[\W])(?=(.*[[]{}()<>.,;:'")){1,}])(?!.*\s).{8,16}$, case 0, canon 0)'

I believe this is because I am not escaping it properly. What are the character that should be escaped?

Comment: Could you please let know what conditions you try to code in the pattern? It seems the pattern does not do what you think it does.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: _Should contain a combination of alphabets,numbers and/or special characters without spaces. 
No consecutive iteration of three similar characters.
The password should not be same as the user name.  
Example username rajsingh and password is rajsingh.  
During registration it should give an error.  
However usename rajsingh and password is RAJSINGH is a valid entry._

Comment: I doubt you can hard-code *the password should not be same as the user name* requirement into the pattern, you'd have to provide it as a variable. If the username can contain special chars, you will have to escape it. Well, perhaps, `"^(?!.*([a-zA-Z0-9])\\1{2})(?=[^a-zA-Z]*[a-zA-Z])(?=\\D*\\d)(?=.*[\\[\\]{}()<>.,;:'\"])\\S{8,16}$"` will be enough. To disallow any string coming as a variable, add `"(?!" + old_user_name + "$)` lookahead after `^` (escaping may be necessary).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: If I discard the rest and only focus on upto 3 similar character then what should be the regex?

Comment: I think `"^(?!.*(.)\\1{2})\\S{8,16}$"` is quite generic: no whitespaces, from eight to sixteen characters, no three identical consecutive ones.

Comment: Please provide more examples that should match. Also, please update the question.

Comment: It's the backslash before the quotation marks. You need a total of 3. One to escape the backslash in the regex, and one to escape the quotation mark. You're also going to need another one right before the apostrophe prior to it.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the quantitative `{1,}` in a lookahead group, that is not possible.

Comment: While `{1,}` makes no sense, it is not the main problem I believe.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: You are right. Even if I remove that I get the same error.